# getting CondaHTTP error: ssl module not available when trying to update anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I try to update conda

I get the error below:

> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>   SSLError(SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available.",),)

I am getting this error inside Cygwin on windows 10

Comment: I've had the same problem under Windows 10 and resolved it according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55635960/5755482) :
Installing the [Win32OpenSSL binaries](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) helped.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which OS you are using. I was having the same problem in Ubuntu (under WSL), and after checking that the anaconda websites were whitelisted in my work network, I solved it by upgrading openssl from 1.1.0g to 1.1.1b.

```
(geo) user@host:~$sudo apt-get upgrade openssl
```

(...)

```
(geo) user@host:~$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

For completeness:

```
(geo) tams00@74PDLQ2:~$ conda info

     active environment : geo
    active env location : /home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/geo
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/tams00/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/tams00/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.12
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
```

(...)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I created a new `conda` environment with no packages in in:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

It worked when I added a common package such `numpy`:

```
conda create --name myenv numpy
```

Answer (score -2):

You may need to enable (disabled by default) the modules/mod_ssl.so within the httpd.conf file. 
In addition there is also an include for the ssl config file:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```